# create an object with different ranch of data on Google App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I want to create a function that creates 2 different objects with a different ranch of data from a Sheet. But it says :
Exception: The parameters (String, String, String, String, String, String, String) don't match the method signature for `SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRangeList.`
the mistake is from the variable let data_Spiceblend

P.S: I'm just a beginner in programming so if you find this question stupid I'm sorry :/
That's what i did :

```
  let sheet = openSheet("Spices list");
  let data_SpiceBlend = sheet.getRangeList('B67:B83','B85:B86','B88:B114','B116:B134','B136:B147','B149:B154','B156:B223','B225').getValues();
  let data_SpiceMix = sheet.getRange("B21:B65","B232:B242").getValues();

  let blend_Obj = {};
  let mix_Obj = {};
  let blendSku = data_SpiceBlend[0];
  let mixSku = data_SpiceMix[0];
  let blendContent = [];
  let mixContent = [];

  for (let row of data_SpiceBlend) {
   obj[blendSku] = blendContent;
   blendSku = row[0];
   blendContent = []; 
    }
  

  for (let row of data_SpiceMix) {
      obj[mixSku] = mixContent;
      mixSku = row[0];
      mixContent = [];
    }
  
  blend_Obj[blendSku] = blendContent;
  mix_Obj[mixSku] = mixContent;
  model.blend = blend_Obj;
  model.mix = mix_Obj;
}
```

Comment: There is no getValues() method for Classs RangeList.  You must use getRanges() and then loop through the range array getting values or value for each range.  It's normally I good idea to read the documention before attempting to use a command and if you have problems then read it again.

Comment: Sorry, I see no sense in this code. Probably it would be easier if you describe the process in plain English. Data --> Step 1 --> Step 2 --> Step 3... --> Result.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*The `getRangeList()` method takes an ***array*** of ranges, specified as strings.*

#### Code Change:

```
let data_SpiceBlend = sheet.getRangeList('B67:B83','B85:B86','B88:B114','B116:B134','B136:B147','B149:B154','B156:B223','B225').getValues()
```

should be:

```
let data_SpiceBlend = sheet.getRangeList(['B67:B83','B85:B86','B88:B114','B116:B134','B136:B147','B149:B154','B156:B223','B225']).getRanges().getValues()
```

Note the `[]` encapsulating the list of A1 notations.

Comment: **NB:** There are additional issues with your code, but I have addressed the question at hand in this answer. If you encounter additional errors, I suggest asking a new question with the details.